# Karma tests: Cancelling of Subscription in finalize does not work

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have this scenario: there is a service taking data from BE. Every call of this service (its method) is subscribed and this subscription is saved to Subscription object, so it can be unsubscribed at any time.

There is also a `finalize` operator to cancel the subscription when the service call and all its subsequences are done.

In 'real world' everything works fine - `finalize` works as expected - cancel subscription after everything is done, problem is testing part. If I `expect` the subscription to be null, the test fails, because the subscription is not cancelled, even if `finalize` was called (proved by debugging). And what is even more unclear to me, there is a flag `isLoading`, which is set before getting data and reset in `finalize` and this is reset both in real world and in tests.

```
// test.component.ts

currentRequestSubscription: Subscription;
isLoading: bool;

setData(): void {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.currentRequestSubscription = this.dataService.getData().pipe(
    finalize(() => {      
      this.currentRequestSubscription.unsubscribe();
      this.currentRequestSubscription = null;
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
  ).subscribe((value) => {
    // process value
  });
}

// test.component.spec.ts

spyOn(dataService, 'getData').and.returnValue(of(new Data));

component.setData();
      
expect(component.currentRequestSubscription).toBe(null); // this fails
expect(component.isLoading).toBe(false);                 // this succeeds
```

So, what is behind this? Why is one variable reset in `finalize` truly reset and the other is not? Is there any way how to handle this correctly?

Comment: Where is `setGraphData` method defined?

Comment: Sorry, it had to be ```setData```. I updated question.

Answer (score 0):

The `setData` is `asynchronous` method, and in your test case you invoke method and then immediately checking for the specific condition as of it is `synchronous` method.

use `component.setData(false);` with  `await`

```
await component.setData(false);

expect(eleComponent.currentRequestSubscription).toBe(null); // this fails
expect(eleComponent.isLoading).toBeFalsy;                 // this succeeds
```

**Note** - If the above solution doesn't work, you place your `expect` within the `setTimeOut` or you can use timer for passage of time.

Comment: Neither does work. And how would you explain that one value is correctly set and the other is not?

Comment: The initial value of `isLoading` is `undefined` and in JS  there are six falsy values: `false, 0, '', null, undefined, and NaN`. Everything else is truthy.

Comment: Well, but I set ``ìsLoading``` to ```true``` just under the method head.